# Set specific html tag from ajax response as variable

Tags: jquery

In my ajax response there I would like to catch the html tag and set it as variable

The html I want to set as variable will look like this:

```
<h2>some title here that will always be different</h2>
```

**Here is my ajax callback**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: dataString,

    //if received a response from the server
    success: function (response) {              
        var header = ???

        },
});
```

Can I somehow catch the above simply looking for the `<h2>..</h2>` or does it require some sort of id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter() to get that.

```
$($.parseHTML(response)).filter("#header").text();
```

This will filter out header id'd element. Add id "header" to your `<h2>` or filter out `<h2>` from your response.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: do you mean add id '#header' to the h2 tag ?

Comment: i did: var header = $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("#header"); then on a new line alert(header); and it came back with object object

Comment: Try var header =  $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("#header").text();

Answer (score 0):

```
var header = response.find("h2").text();
```

You might want to go more in depth with the selector, in case there are more h2-tags on the page.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: dataString
}).done(function(data) {
    var header = data.find("h2:first").text();
});
```

Comment: just in case there are multiple, is there a way to restrict to the first h2 tag ? would giving the h2 tag an id make things easier?

Comment: Simply use `.find("h2:first")` that should work. Alternatively you can do `.find("h2").first().text()`.

Comment: i tried this but alert(header); never popped up ?var header = response.find("h2").text();

Comment: @user3436467 Where did you put the alert(header) ?

Comment: new line directly after: var header = response.find("h2").text();

Comment: @user3436467 Do alert(response) and see what it responds with.

Comment: there is a lot of data in the response html tables etc but the h2 tag is at the very top

Comment: @user3436467 Check my edit and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `find('h2:first')[0].outerHTML` to get the first `h2` as string.

```
success: function (response) {              
    var header = $(response).find('h2:first')[0].outerHTML;
    alert(header);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("h2")` is how you can select it with jQuery